# pgfplots plot stops at x-value of 5

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I have a short question. I made the pgfplot below. But somehow all the functions are only shown to the x-value of 5. It behaves "normal" when the definitions

```
[
width=10cm, height=7.5cm,
xmin=0, xmax=30,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
xlabel=Zeit / min,
ylabel= Temperatur / °C,
]
```

aren't there.
Does anybody know the reason for this?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm, height=7.5cm,
xmin=0, xmax=30,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
xlabel=Zeit / min,
ylabel= Temperatur / °C,
]

\addplot+[
    no markers,
    ultra thick,
    color=red,
    ultra thick,
    %] coordinates{(0,85) (25,10)};
    ]{-3*x+80};

\addplot+[
    sharp plot, 
    no markers,
    color=blue,
    ultra thick,
    ]{-2.033*x+80};

\addplot+[ 
    no markers,
    color=magenta,
    ultra thick,
    ]{x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include `domain=0:30`. The default domain is `-5:5`, thus your plots will stop at `x=5`.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,version=last,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm, height=7.5cm,
xmin=0, xmax=30,
ymin=0, ymax=100,
xlabel=Zeit / min,
ylabel= Temperatur / °C,
domain=0:30
]

\addplot+[
    no markers,
    ultra thick,
    color=red,
    ultra thick,
    %] coordinates{(0,85) (25,10)};
    ]{-3*x+80};

\addplot+[
    sharp plot,
    no markers,
    color=blue,
    ultra thick,
    ]{-2.033*x+80};

\addplot+[
    no markers,
    color=magenta,
    ultra thick,
    ]{x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]